# C++ Math: Fitting a complicated function is not working

Tags: c++, math, wolfram-mathematica, levenberg-marquardt

I've been trying to get this fitting operation to work since more than 10 days. I wrote a C++ class for fitting using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, and I tested it with simple polynomials and the fit is a success; but with the real experimental function I need for my experiment, it's not working.

The same function I fitted with Mathematica, and it was OK to do it there (but slow, 12 seconds per fit, which is why I'm using C++). My program acts crazy and returns wrong results when I do the fit. Could you please check the functions I use and tell me whether anything is wrong?

The following is the procedure of fitting which I use in my class. Again, I'd like to mention that it worked with polynomials, so I could've have done a very deep mistake here that conflicts with only some special functions... that's my assumption.

---

The initial values I use are very close to the correct ones.

If you need any additional information, please let me know. Any help is very highly appreciated.

Comment: Why is 12 seconds per fit bad, especially if you only have to do it once?  You can fit a lot of 12 second fits into ten days of useless effort.

Comment: I have to do it 500000 times. I'm doing noise-stability measurements and measuring the Allan Standard Deviation.

Comment: And later I have to use this fitting with an interactive system connected with an FPGA to fit some data simultaneously; i.e., this fit has to be done as fast as possible. Even if Mathematica could do my 500000 for now (which will take 64 days), I'll have to write this C++ program sooner or later.

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or extra print statements, etc.) to isolate the problem, using a simple data-set.  Once you have a 10-line [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org), then come back with a question about that.

Comment: Which is the function you are fitting? Is it the first one, FIDFunc?

Comment: Yes Phil, it's the first one. And the others are the derivatives with respect to the parameter name mentioned after _D_. Sorry about posting such a stupid quesion in the sense that it's long. I, myself, don't like to answer people with such long codes, but I did everything I can, and that's why I need help from someone with experience with fitting.

Comment: You might have to do it 500,000 times, but do they need to be serial?  Can you leverage multithreading or GPUs here?  At 12 seconds per fit, you'll need 69 days to do all this work.  Even if you're brilliant and reduce the fit time by a factor of ten you're still faced with a week of day and night computation.  Sure your 500K repetitions isn't hyperbole?

Comment: Not sure if this will be any help, but I recently came across [this](http://www.trentfguidry.net/post/2011/12/10/Implementing-Levenberg-Marquardt-algorithm-nonlinear-least-squares-regression-multiple-weighted-simultaneous-functions-in-C-sharp.aspx) implementation in C#. I've no idea if it is correct, but maybe comparing it with your code might help you work out what the problem might be.

Comment: I'm gonna parallelise the code on C++ later, because I have to do it anyway (and it's easy with OpenMP). It's inevitable for me to parallelise this code on C++, since I have to run it with the experiment, as I mentioned. But on Mathematica, there's no way I could use this in the real experiment.

Comment: Thank you, Benjol, for your code. I'll try to see whether it helps. Actually, I have the code from Numerical Recipes 3, but it's very complicated and without comments, and done in a stupid way. That's why I couldn't compare with it. I'll see if that code could help (although I don't speak C#).

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you mean it won't converge? Have you examined the condition number of the matrix that you are trying to invert?? Why not try QR instead of matrix inversion?

Comment: What is QR? ChiSquare decreases, but the parameters don't reach the correct values from the experiment. That's what happens.

Comment: Whenever you have a linear system to solve, you generally try to avoid actually inverting the matrix to avoid numerical errors. QR factorisation is a method of factorization of your matrix that allows you to solve the system without inverting the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, mathematician1975. I'm currently using Gaussian elemination. I'll try to use QR factorisation and see whether that changes anything. Perhaps you're right. This could be the only reasonable explanation for why the program works for one function and not the other.

Comment: What is the data you are approximating taken from? Are they random points or are you sampling from some other function?? What is the functional approximation form you are using to approximate the data?

Comment: The data is a result of exactly the same function with sum slight white- and pink-noise added to it. It's produced by a simulation. Yesterday I plotted the data I want to fit and plotted the function with the approximate result expected. They looked exactly the same!!

Comment: I need your help with your experience, guys. The question is, what's the case that would make a polynomial fit correctly with no problems and such a function not fit? I think here lies the key problem. I'm gonna learn about QR Decomposition and apply its algorithm. If you have any other ideas in mind, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I would rather migrate it to reviewmycode, than close.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a quick look reveals that you should have

```
   parameters -= SamArray<T>::MatrixProduct(SamArray<T>::Inverse(JTJ + combinationMatrix),J); //add the new deltas to the parameters and test them

   instead of 

   parameters += SamArray<T>::MatrixProduct(SamArray<T>::Inverse(JTJ + combinationMatrix),J); //add the new deltas to the parameters and test them
```

That is, of course, assuming that `J` is the gradient and not the negative gradient.
This is the case with any Newton or quasi-Newton method (like Levenberg-Marquardt).

Comment: That's pretty reasonable. Actually, I thought about this, and when I was testing my class with polynomials, it -= didn't work, and that's why I thought of +=... I have no idea why this is the case. Now I tried them both, and both aren't working... Now in the case of -=, ChiSquare increases in each step, or in other words, the update process doesn't work, because ChiSquare is always larger in each step... Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @SamerAfach No offense, but it sounds like you are stabbing blindly. If neither works, then I suggest going back and re-deriving all your math to gain a deeper understanding. It should be `-=` if you have Hessian (or an approximation to it) and gradient and `+=` if you have the Hessian (or approx.) and negative gradient. Note, this is true for both maximization and minimization problems.

Comment: Actually you're right. I'm kinda stabbing in the dark. I applied this algorithm in Mathematica (without the combination matrix) and it worked for a complicated function (a + b arctan(c x + d)), and in my current program I tried to understand as much as possible, and the program worked with no problems for simple polynomials... but not for this god damn function :(. I thought the derivatives of the function could be wrong. But apparently something else is messed up. But if you all confirm that everything is alright, then there's something else to look at. I'll tripple-check everything. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't confirm that everything is alright, I just saw one potential error.

Comment: The gradient was negative. That's why it didn't work with the -=. Thanks for the hint. (The problem is, however, isn't fixed).

Comment: @SamerAfach you mean you computed the negative of the gradient I hope (and not that the values of the gradient were negative numbers.)

Comment: Yes, the negative of the gradient was what I calculated. It just has to do with the order of the subtraction when calculating the right side of the linear system. So it's not a big deal. :)

Comment: Hell!!! IT HAS WORKED... Guess what I did?! I just removed the Marquardt contribution... I replaced the combination matrix with I*lambda, where I is the identity matrix... could you provide any explanation to this?!

Comment: @SamerAfach Yeah, your Hessian matrix likely isn't right. Double and triple check that.

Comment: But I took it from Wikipedia... the combination matrix can be the Hessian matrix + JTJ... if that's wrong, then one has to remove it from Wikipedia!! Check it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm   it states there clearly (JTJ + lambda*diag(JTJ))... is that wrong?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that this is just an approximation to the Hessian. Plus you could have computed it wrong.  Also note that if your function could be simply hard to optimize (even with LM)

Comment: Very well. Thank you for your help :). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than discussing the reasons for the code not giving you the result you expect, I'm going to address the speed issues. You have in your code

```
parameters += SamArray<T>::MatrixProduct(SamArray<T>::Inverse(JTJ + combinationMatrix),J);
```

which first calculates a matrix inverse and then multiplies by `J`, which I presume is another matrix. This is inefficient as it is fundamentally the same as solving `A X = I` first, then calculating `A^-1 B`, where `A` and `X` are matrices and `I` is the identity matrix. Instead, it is better to solve, `A X = B`, directly. There are several decomposition schemes that enable you to this, such as [QR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) and [LU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Applications). In LU decomposition, the matrix `A` is broken into an upper, `U`, and lower, `L`, triangular parts which are then efficiently inverted separately, as follows

```
A X = L U X = B
U X = L^-1 B
X = U^-1 L^-1 B
```

and this is performed as part of the algorithm itself. If you want the inverse, directly, then you would replace `B` with `I`, but as you can see, there is no need. Looking at the [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm#The_solution), it may be the case that `Transpose[J].J + DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal@J]`, using Mathematica notation, may be positive definite, then [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) is available, and it is significantly faster. But, I have not looked closely at the algorithm, so Cholesky decomposition may not be usable, in this case.

**\begin{edit}**
In [sec 1.5 of ch. 3](http://www.ec-securehost.com/SIAM/ot60.html), Stewart discusses the relative speeds of the two algorithms: invert-then-multiply v. LU decomposition. Both have the same asymptotic complexity, `O(n^3)`, but they differ in the coefficient. Specifically, when solving the equation `A X == B`, invert-then-multiply has an operation count of `5 n^3 /6 + l n^2` while LU has `n^3 /3 + l n^2` where `n` is the number of rows in `B` and `l` is the number of columns. The ratio of the two is always greater than one, and even when `l == n`, LU decomposition is 30% faster than invert-then-multiply.
**\end{edit}**

Secondly, you are calculating Chi square twice for each set of parameters: once when they are determined initially, and again when you compare them to the next iteration. This value should be cached alongside the previous accepted parameters.

Lastly, I would not discount Mathematica's ability to handle fitting at a [reasonable speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=fitting).

Comment: Thanks for the precious info. Actually J is a column matrix (single column). Does that change anything?

Comment: @SamerAfach No, it doesn't. You're still solving the equivalent of `A X = I`, and then multiplying `A^-1 b`.

Comment: Hello rcollyer. I have a question. Why is it different to decompose the matrix into LU, invert both LU matrices, then multiply them with the right side, than just using the Gaussian elimination to invert the matrix and then multiply it with the right side? Why would you call this "direct solving of the linear system"? could you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my program to do gaussian elimination with the column of the right-side to get the solution. Would that be OK?

Comment: @Sam When you learned Gaussian elimination, did you ever work with [augmented matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix)? If so, then creating an inverse is that process with the augmented portion being the identity matrix. The same number of steps are required if instead, `A` is augmented by `B`, as in the equation `A X = B`. In other words, during the elimination process, the equation is solved with few extra steps.

Comment: Yeah exactly, this is what I'm doing now (and it's what I was doing before to find the inverse, but instead I just attach the coeffs of the linear system on the right side rather than the identity matrix). Would that introduce any kind of precision errors? Would you have any suggestions against that? Why would using LU decomposition be better (if it's better)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sam I don't know. As far as I know, LU is doing roughly the same thing just there are adjustments to reduce numerical errors, like introducing a permuation matrix in pivoted LU. The other advantage is the inversion part of LU is fast as your inverting triangular matrices. I'd suggest using an LAPACK implementation to do this for you as it is likely already been tested.

Comment: @Sam I added a reference in my answer about the relative speeds of the two algorithms.

Comment: Thanks man :). I recently achieved fitting 60000 points in 1 second with a single core :)